# begin() and end() as member functions in a range-based for loop

Tags: c++, c++11

**EDIT:** The problem described in this question is caused by a non-conforming compiler (see details in the comments).

Assume Generator is a class with member functions `begin()` and `end()`. It is my understanding that according to the C++11 standard, in a range-based loop:

```
 Generator g; 
 for (auto el: g) ;
```

the Generator's member functions `begin()` and `end()` are the ones which will be used in the loop.

I made a smallest code which demonstrates that (below). However, the code only compiles fine when I uncomment the first line. That is, it only works when

```
   #include<iostream>
```

is included. In the opposite case, it produces the error:

```
  ‘begin’ was not declared in this scope (likewise for 'end').
```

I have come across many questions & answers which relate to range-based loops in the new standard, but don't see the reason for this error.

```
//#include<iostream>

 class Iterator{    
 public: 
  Iterator (int i_) : i(i_) 
  {}

  bool operator!=(const Iterator &other) const {
    return i != other.i;
  }

  int operator*() const{
    return i; 
  }

  void operator++(){
    ++i;
  }

private:
  int i; 
};

struct Generator{

  Iterator begin()
  {
    return Iterator(0); 
  }

  Iterator end(){
    return Iterator(100); 
  }
}; 



int main(){

  Generator g; 

  for (int i : g)
    {
      // do something. 
    }

}
```

Comment: [Cannot reproduce.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7246f8ee6208712)

Comment: Compiles for me with gcc 4.8.1. Only warning is unused `i`.

Comment: Are you by any chance using an older compiler? Early in the specification of range-based `for`, it was intended to always use **non**-member `begin`/`end` (since these defer to the member versions anyway). That may be what it is trying to do.

Comment: Thank you very much. That solves my problem ... just couldn't get my head around it. g++ 4.6.4, tried to compile with g++ --std=c++-x.

Comment: Glad that's sorted then. I kind of feel like this question should be closed, but I'm not sure what as... or should it be answered, with "use a Standard-conforming compiler"?

Comment: I've added a note to the very beginning of the question regarding the compiler issue.

Answer (score 3):

**CORRECTED**: The C++11 for-each loop uses the following logic given `for (auto i : c)`:

1. use `c` and `c + length` if the type is an array where the length is deducible;
2. use `c.begin()` and `c.end()` if the type is a class/struct containing those member functions;
3. use `begin(c)` and `end(c)` via argument dependent lookup if the above fails.

The C++11 for-each loop uses `std::begin` and `std::end`, which by default forwards to a container's `begin`/`end` functions. This is done to allow for e.g. specializing on arrays. These definitions need to be visible at the point at which the for loop is declared.

The definitions of these functions are not implicitly included. This is why you get an error without the `#include` statement.

They are defined in the `<iterator>` header, which is included when you include `<iostream>`. This is why the program compiles when `<iostream>` is included.

Therefore, the compiler is not performing steps 1 and 2 of the standard and is relying on the standard library begin/end to perform them.

Comment: @BoBTFish, well, it's not totally wrong. The last thing the compiler tries is to use the `begin` and `end` free functions.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include the behaviour specified in the standard.